# fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I am pretty new to the MacOS so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to compile a programme on my Mac (M1 chip with arm64 architecture, Mac OS Monterey) which requires x86_64 architecture and gfortran. I installed a x86_64 version of `brew`, `clang`, `gcc`, `gsl` and `pkg-config`. However I am getting an error where the compiler is unable to find the header file:

```
Running cmake.
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:2 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0002 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran - skipped
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 - yes
Defaulting to gfortran
-- Found PythonInterp: /Users/lg268561/opt/anaconda3/envs/kcap_env/bin/python (found version "3.9.7") 
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Found GSL: /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7/include (found suitable version "2.7", minimum required is "2.1") 

-- Looking for gfortran related libraries...
-- Extracting library and header information by calling 'gfortran -v'...
-- 'gfortran -v' returned:
-- Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/11.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1/lib/gcc/11 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,d --program-suffix=-11 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-zstd=/usr/local/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_1' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --enable-libphobos --build=x86_64-apple-darwin21 --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --without-build-config --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_1) 

-- Detected gfortran version 11.2.0
-- Architecture string: Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21
-- Detected gfortran architecture: x86_64-apple-darwin21
-- Detected gfortran prefix: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1
-- Detected default gfortran exec-prefix
-- Detected gfortran exec-prefix: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1
-- Found --libdir flag -- yes
-- gfortran libraries path: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1/lib/gcc/11
-- gfortran include path dir: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1/lib/gcc/11/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21/11.2.0/include
-- Found GFortranLibs: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_1/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.dylib (found version "11.2.0") 
-- Looking for gfortran libraries -- found
-- gfortran version: 11.2.0
CMake Deprecation Warning at cosebis/CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0002 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


GSL_INC:/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7/include
GSL_LIB:/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7/lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/lg268561/Downloads/kcap/build
Running make.
[  0%] Built target GSL
[  5%] Running make for cosebis
make[3]: Entering directory `/Users/lg268561/Downloads/kcap/cosebis'
make[4]: Entering directory `/Users/lg268561/Downloads/kcap/cosebis/modules'
clang: warning: -lgsl: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lgslcblas: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
matrix.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include "unistd.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Attempts at a solution from reading off the web:

-When I check the gfortran include path directories, the header file is there.

-Delete everything in the `/Library/Developer/CommandTools/` directory and reran `xcode-select --install` but the error persists.

-I've aliased my gcc and clang to the x86_64 versions, located in the `/usr/local/` directory. `gcc -v` gives:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and `clang -v` gives:

```
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I've symlinked every version of MacOSX.sdk in my `SDKs/` folder. The problem still persists.

### Edit

I checked the CMake error log:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

could it be a problem with linked libraries instead?

Comment: Is it just unistd.h that is missing or are others like stdio.h unusable also?

Comment: Other header files can't be found either...

Comment: You might try running "sudo opensnoop" in a Terminal window while you run your compiler; that will list out the files the compiler is trying to open, which might at least give you an idea of where it is looking for header files.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I tried this, just gives a lot of 'invalid user access in action #11 ...'